# Angular datepicker downside of input field

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker, mat-form-field

When i tried to open angular material datepicker it was opening upside of an input field.
How to make it to open downside of an input field.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100 date-class">
          <mat-label class="required">End Date</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="picker2"
            (dateChange)="onEndDateChange($event)"
            [min]="todayDate"
            formControlName="toDate"
            readonly
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker2 yPosition="below"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control where the drop will be places you couls use parameters like: DatepickerDropdownPositionX, DatepickerDropdownPositionY (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)

```js
type DatepickerDropdownPositionY = 'above' | 'below';
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Could share a snippet?

Comment: Added the sample code in the question